# How permissions bitmask should look like with view/edit/add/remove permissions. How to use it?

Tags: php

User can view/edit/add/remove objects (categories, users, items etc.). What is the best practice to store (in MySQL), manage and check if user have such permissions.

`Acl` class will control if user allowed to execute controller's method or not.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using binary-string stored as hex value in database.

When I've read hex value (permissions) from database for appropriate client I convert it to binary string where every digit (0 or 1) represents state of some permission flag. Permission flags has been defined by position in binary-string. e.g

```
0 -> can read
1 -> can write
2 -> can access gallery
3 -> can access pools
4 -> can ban users
5 -> can drink beer
...
```

When needed, just validate every binary digit with appropriate permission and store it in permission array as boolean value.

Also, I have stored some permissions as groups like administrators, moderators, gallery editors, etc...

Look here: [`Which data type is suitable for storing this situation?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5665831/which-data-type-is-suitable-for-storing-this-situation/5666619#5666619) for better explanation and examples.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to go with bitmasks?

If you have many roles your bitmask number can get very high, and a query to search who has permission X would be bad performance wise.

Personally, I like to store such data in a two column table (UserId, PermissionId), this way it's both scalable and easy to maintain. To check who has a permission or which permissions has a user, you only need a SELECT or a JOIN.

Comment: Hehe, of course, I'm not sure that I'd like to use a bitmask for permissons. So, you have some class with defined permisson_id constants and table (UserId, PermissionId), right?

Comment: I don't like the constants approach, because will force you to manually handle permissions. You should define them in the database too, and manage the permission both for users and objects (pages, topics, whatever) through an admin. This way, you'll never touch the code again to manage the permissions.

Comment: E.g. You must apply permission to manage who can view the pages of your web site. You can lay out your database like this: `Pages (PageId, PagePath, PageTitle)`, `Roles (RoleId, RoleName)` `PagesRoles (PageId, RoleId)`, `Users (UserId, UserName)` and `UsersRoles (UserId, RoleId)`. To check if a user can see a page you only have to do `select count(*) from PagesRoles a join UserRoles b on b.RoleId = a.RoleId where a.PageId = ? and b.UserId = ?`. Having an admin for roles, pages and user will give you the power to manage permission in a split second.