# Which data type is suitable for storing this situation?

Tags: php, javascript, types

For example, I have a user, and the user have different user right, for example, a user can have

```
-create file
-read file
-update file
-delete file
```

4 rights, I can use 4 BOOL to find the user right, but if the user have more right, I need create more and more BOOL to store the right. I don't think it is a good idea. And I think of getting a long integer for this... for example, the user can do all the stuff is 1111.
create file is 1000, read file is 100, update is 10, delete is 1. So, if the user only get read file right is 0100.

Is there any better ideas?? Thank you.

Comment: I'ld recommend you to use a long integer. Very light, very strong. Where do you need it (C++, (My)SQL, etc.)?

Comment: Will there ever be more than 31 or 32 access right types?

Comment: php & javascript... ....

Comment: Take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380045/why-should-i-use-bitwise-bitmask-in-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to convert privileges (rights) in binary-state-string and later, store it in database as long integer or hexadecimal string (VARCHAR; for storing a lot of rights).

Example

```
$privileges_list = array(
  0 => 'create_file',
  1 => 'read_file',
  2 => 'update_file',
  3 => 'delete_file',
  4 => 'create_pool',
  5 => 'vote_in_pool',
  6 => 'create_gallery',
  7 => 'upload_images',
  8 => 'view_statistics'
);
```

So if you want to set `create file`, `update file` and `view statistics` rights to the user just put 1 on appropriate positions in string (0, 2, 8) and 0 for rest of them

```
$binary_string = "100000101";
```

Last character in this string is position 0, first is position 8.

Now you can convert this string to integer (261) or hex-number (105) and put it into database as privilege-set for that user (I prefer hex).

To convert this value back to privileges-list you can use something like this

```
function hexvalue2privileges($hexvalue, $plist) {
  $res = array(); $res_assoc = array();
  for ($i = strlen($hexvalue) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    $bin = str_pad(decbin(hexdec(substr($hexvalue, $i, 1))), 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $bin_array = array_reverse(str_split($bin, 1));
    foreach ($bin_array as $bitstate) $res[] = $bitstate == '1' ? true : false;
    }
  foreach ($plist as $key => $id) {
    $res_assoc[$id] = $res[$key];
    }
  return $res_assoc;
  }
```

and call this function

```
print_r(hexvalue2privileges('105', $privileges_list));
```

Output will be

```
Array
(
    [create_file] => 1      // true
    [read_file] =>          // false
    [update_file] => 1      // true
    [delete_file] =>        // false
    [create_pool] =>        // false
    [vote_in_pool] =>       // false
    [create_gallery] =>     // false
    [upload_images] =>      // false
    [view_statistics] => 1  // true
)
```

With every hexadecimal character you can store 4 rights so to calculate number of character needed use this formula

```
$chars_needed = floor((count($privileges_list)-1) / 4) + 1; // result 3
```

To get total length of binary-string

```
$binary_length = $chars_needed * 4; // result 12
```

To fix length of privileges set

```
$binary_string = "100000101";
$binary_string = str_pad($binary_string, $binary_length, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
// result '000100000101'
```

To convert $binary_string to hex

```
$binary_string = "000100000101";

$hexvalue = "";
$groups = str_split($binary_string, 4);
foreach ($groups as $group) $hexvalue .= dechex(bindec($group));

// result $hexvalue='105'   (1=0001, 0=0000, 5=0101)
```

Also you can create groups of privileges and assign them to users by creating privileges-set for every group (administrators, moderators, guests, vip, etc).

Hope this helps

Comment: @Charliepiga, you're right. phpBB uses very similar system for storing rights for users.

Answer (score 1):

Use  `[flags CHAR(10) default '0000000000']`
Whenever you need any digit, you can use it like

1st digit - New
2nd digit - Edit etc.

At the time of storing, you just need to change that bit and store like this 1100000000. That's it.